# Why haven't I been awarded the famous question badge twice?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, badges, badge-progress

**Famous Question Badge Description:**
Asked a question with 10,000 views. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

**Problem :**

I have a question with 25k + views. 
I have not been awarded this badge multiple times.

**Question:**

Wtf ?

Comment: So you did ask that question twice?

Comment: It only gets awarded once per question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That badge is only awarded once per question.  So you have one (singular) question with more than 10,000 views.  You have thus been awarded a (singular) badge to show your accomplishment.  If you have two questions with more than 10,000 views and have not been given the badge twice, please post about it.